# How to re-upload an extension with a deleted extension-ID?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have a chrome extension with an existing extension Id and a local update file (on our server) that is used by many users.

I uploaded the extension to the extension store successfully. 
Seeing I needed to make some changes I deleted the extension from the store.

I made the required changes and tried to upload the amended extension file again (with the same id). I got the error: ""An error occurred: Gallery system error, please try again later."

I read in some forums that I should wait. I'ved tried a few times and it almost 2 weeks since my first uplaod and I still cannot upload my new extension.

How can I resolve this?
Is there something that can be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean deleted? The Chrome Web Store does not let you delete items.

Comment: I was able to delete it. It was before it was approved.

Comment: My suggestions would be to either push an update to your current extension that prompts users to install a new extension with a different ID or email the extension group and hope someone at Google can help. https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome Web Store does not allow duplicate upload even after deletion, we reserve the ID forever, however we do not have clear message indicating this so people delete item casually, we have improved the message. This has become a common problem as Chrome M21 forbids apps installation from outside of CWS, we should communicate this better.

If you have strong reason to need the item id back (such as you have already been distributing the item under the ID for a long time), please post your item ID and CWS account email at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138706 and we can try do a manual recover for you as an exception.

Sorry for this inconvenience.

Comment: We actually talked to you guys a while ago, and understood that which is a shame as we have a commercial product we shipped under one ID, and cannot now include the same ID in the store on all the client machines

We will use this form and try to install it this way.

Does this mean from v21 you cannot use an Installation file anymore to install a chrome extension??