# How do I delete an extension in my Chrome developer dashboard?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have uploaded an extension to my dashboard but I don't want to publish it any more. The extension remained "draft" status, and I want to get it removed from the dashboard. However, I cannot find any way to do so so far. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can't delete an extension from the Chrome developer dashboard.

In the past, there was a delete button at the dashboard, but it has been removed because developers accidentally removed apps/extensions (and then [tried to re-upload the app/extension with the same ID, which failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225314/how-to-re-upload-an-extension-with-a-deleted-extension-id)).

Unpublished extensions/apps do not count toward the extension limit, so there are no consequences for having a lot of unpublished apps/extensions besides the clutter at the dashboard.

If you're really bothered by the entry at your dashboard, create a user style, user script or extension to hide it.

Comment: But extensions can't run on the webstore. I just create a new item and replace it.

Comment: Regular Chrome extensions cannot modify the web store indeed. But you can use a different browser if you want to, e.g. Firefox or a custom Chromium build.

Comment: There's still a hacky way to do it though, isn't there?

Comment: @Xan Yes there is. I'm not going to explain them in public though, for obvious reasons (abuse).

Comment: Okay, what I meant is "isn't there a hacky way documented here on SO already"? Edit: okay, not on SO. But I was able to find it. Anyway, if you think it's best left unearthed so be it.

Comment: @Xan My answers about extending devtools can also be generalized and be applied to the dashboard, I guess that you're referring to that?.

Comment: No, there is literally a blog post about removing a Webstore item from the dashboard page.

Comment: @Xan You mean `cxDeleteItem`? That does not work (you'll get a 403 forbidden and the item won't be deleted).

Comment: Yes, I was referring to that. Good to know.

Comment: Thanks a lot to you guys. BTW `cxDeleteItem` seems not to work now. :(

Comment: Clutter is a non-trivial consequence, and a user style to remove clutter is just more clutter. Thanks for the info.

Comment: There's just an archive button to solve clutter problem.

Answer (score 9):

The new beta dashboard has an archive option. (more -> archive)

Comment: This only works for drafts, not published extensions?

Comment: See the answer below, the new dashboard doesn't have "unpublish" so you have to do that from the old dashboard, then go to the new dashboard to archive. Stupid, but it works.

Answer (score 8):

You can not delete an extension/APP from the developer dashboard of chrome web store.

Chrome web store have released new developers dashboard. You can Archive an extension/APP from the same.

It is possible that developers accidentally removed extensions/APP. Then using the same extension/APP id for publication is not possible. To handle these type of human mistakes its mandatory to first unpublish the extension/APP and then Archive the same.

Steps to Archive the extension/APP:

1. Open old developers dashboard:
   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard
2. click on respective unpublish button of your extension
3. Open new developers
   dashboard:  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/devconsole
4. Select your extension from the given list
5. Click on "MORE" (top right corner)
6. Select "Archive"
7. Done

Note: We do not have unpublish option in new developers dashboard. Because its still in beta phase. So for unpublish the extension, you can still use old dashboard.

Comment: Is there a way to unarchive an extension?

Comment: @Quantumplation yes, basically by repeating the same steps you followed to archive an extension.

Answer (score 7):

To distinguish between real and "deleted" extensions you can upload "fake" version of "deleted" extension. This version contain only 1 file `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "(deleted)",
    "description": "(deleted)",
    "version": "0"
}
```

Also you can delete icons, screenshots and promo images (if any).

Later, if "deleted" extension was never installed by users, it can be replaced with another real extension (Chrome Store does not store old versions).

Or better use a new "archive" dashboard option.

Comment: But you have to have a version greater than the previous version

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you actually **CAN** delete an item. I did it just a few minutes ago.

Quoting [Chris Alexander's blog:](http://chris-alexander.co.uk/on-engineering/google/deleting-items-from-the-chrome-webstore-developer-dashboard/)

> To do the delete, open the dashboard, and open the Chrome developer tools (Ctrl + Shift + J). Your app ID is the string that is on the end of the URL that you get when you click “Edit” next to it. Type in the console:
>
> ```
> cxDeleteItem('id')
> ```

**EDIT 22-08-2018:** It looks like this method no longer works since long time ago.

Comment: This does not work now. It was mentioned in the comments above and I had tried it. It seems that you can no longer delete an add-on permanently.

Answer (score 0):

First you should "unpublish" your extension. Then you can archieve it so it won't be in the default list of applications.

I just used it to clean up my list with old applications I published and where all still listed (drafts). You cannot directly archive a published app (options are greyed out untill you edit something).