# Remove audience of chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Please tell me if the extension was removed (taken down from Chrome Webstore or account was suspended) after 3 months will be it deleted from the Webstore finally? And will be it removed from computers of all users (which  previously installed it) or not?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would depend on *how* it was removed.

If a developer unpublishes the extension, it is [not deleted from Web Store database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233063/how-do-i-delete-an-extension-in-my-chrome-developer-dashboard), and existing installs will continue to exist but no new installs will happen.

If Google catches a malicious extension, it will be, in addition, remotely disabled on users' machines. It's hard to say if it's "deleted" from Web Store or simply unpublished.

Those are the 2 extreme situations. In-between there can be a whole spectrum. If an extension is delisted pending some changes, I'm not sure what happens with existing installs. Google probably explains that when it notifies a developer.