# Remove extension of inactive google developer account from Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Does anyone know how to remove a published extension from the Google Chrome Web Store that is tied to an inactive or deleted Google account?

Comment: Have you tried to inquire in the [documentation FAQ](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/faq) if this is possible? I've been checking post and I've only found topics of [deleting extensions in dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233063/how-do-i-delete-an-extension-in-my-chrome-developer-dashboard) not in Chrome Web store. So could you give it a shot?

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for your reply. I’ve gone through the FAQ documentation and can’t find the info I need. The information you provided isn’t related to my situation. We have a plugin that was published and tied to an account that was deleted due to a google account migration. Eventually we uploaded an updated plugin with a new active account, but now we have 2 in the chrome web store and can’t unpublish the original plugin that is tied to the deleted account.