# How to delete Chrome web store Developer Items (extensions)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there really no option to delete the extensions that I previously created here and I am supposed to just overwrite them with new ones?

[image: Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard Items page:]

[image: Menu for extension edit three dots:]

Comment: No, I can't delete it. Already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233063/how-do-i-delete-an-extension-in-my-chrome-developer-dashboard